# Different EDIT form views in SharePoint 2013 / InfoPath

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, infopath, form

What is the best way (or maybe easiest way) to do this?:

I'm trying to have multiple views of a list form.  One view will have fewer columns available than the other.  This way, one set of people gets one view, the other set gets the other view with more columns available.  Mind you, I'm using InfoPath and SP2013.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As per me it can be implemented in two ways - having only one view but display the particular section of the view(some columns) for the respective users and other section of the same view(with some more columns) for rest other respective users. This rules you can define on the form load rules for show hide columns. Similarly, as an alternate you we can have two views for different set of columns and based on the users on form load rule display the particular view.

Comment: Both of your options make sense.  How would I go about implementing this?

Comment: @DanJ: The way we implement the other infopath form, we need to start with designing the form and play with show hide field rule on form load event based on username() function... something like if username () eq "this user"  show these fields or hide these fields.... and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Per my experience, this can be controlled by 'status', for different 'status',load different view.

Below demo used for worklfow, while the logic is smililar

[image]

[image]

https://sharepoint.fpweb.net/sharepoint-blog/how-to-create-multiple-views-in-infopath/